# Expectation of $v=\inf \{n\geq 2\,;\, X_n > X_1 \}$ when $(X_n)$ is i.i.d. uniform on (0,1)

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $W$ be the occurence meaning the following ordering : $X_1...X_k$ where $X_k$ is greatest.. $X_k$ is greatest, and next in order is $X_1$, and the order of the others is not important. Because of the independence of the occurrences and equal distributions of the variables , we have $**P\{v=k\}={1 \over k(k-1)}**; k=2...$ Therefore $Ev= \infty$

I highlighted what I don't understand , can anyone clarify this with a little more detail?

Comment: your assumption that 'the others is not important' is not correct. methinks. v=k , actually means $X_{k-1}, X_{k-2}...X_2$ are greater than $X_1$. and for the rest n-k+1 $X_i$ ...they are to be arranged . and sum of probabilities of all possible arrangements of them will give the probability of our interest.

Comment: and notice one thing. the probability that you have calculated if summed over 2 to n, doesn't give 1.

Comment: do you know the final answer ? then i can try ..!!

Comment: It says that the variable doesn;t have a expected value. Which is what Ev is here. This was the idea given, idk honestly.. Can you give it a try ?

Comment: sorry in 1st comment , that'd be 'less than' in stead of greater than. anyway..
 your book has written that the random variable 'v' doesn't have an expected value ? are the lines " Let occurrence $W=\{v=k\}$ mean that $X_k$ is greatest, and next in order is $X_1$, and the order of the others is not important. Because of the independence of the occurrences and equal distributions of the variables , we have $**P\{v=k\}={1 \over k(k-1)}**; k=1,2...$ Therefore $Ev= \infty$ " quoted from your book ?

or you made that logic ?

Comment: I translated this

Comment: Forgot: $Ev= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} k {1 \over k(k-1)}=+ \infty$

Comment: okay. but there's mistake you have done while translating. you have written k start from '1' . that's not true. it starts from '2'

Comment: Forgot: Let W be the following ordering : $X_1...X_k$ where $X_k$ is greatest..

Comment: Now checked three times, everything translated very precisely..

Comment: I'd like to hear your thoughts, now that I edited, if it changes anything ?

Comment: The event that $X_k>X_1>X_i$ for every $1<i<k$ can happen for at most one index $k>1$. Call $L_k$ and $S_k$ the indices of the largest and second largest value in $(X_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant k}$. By symmetry $(L_k,S_k)$ is uniform on the set of $(\ell,s)$ such that $1\leqslant\ell\ne s\leqslant k$, and this set has size $k(k-1)$ hence $P(L_k=k,S_k=1)=1/(k(k-1))$. Since $[L_k=k,S_k=1]=[\nu=k]$, you are done. Finally, note that $1/(k(k-1))=1/(k-1)-1/k$ hence $\sum\limits_{k>1}1/(k(k-1))=1$.

Comment: A more direct approach is to note that $[\nu>n]$ occurs when $X_1=\max\{X_i\,;\,1\leqslant i\leqslant n\}$, which, again by symmetry, happens with probability $1/n$ for every $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: what confuses me is when you say $L_k$ and ${S_k}$ are largest and second largest in value, but isnt in this idea 1 fixed as second largest ?

Comment: so I conclude 1/k-1 I cant understand for some reason why 1/k(k-1)

Comment: but @Did why will that sum over 1k(k-1) run upto infinity ?'k' can't be greater than 'n' right ? and if that runs upto 'n' . then the sum is not 1.

Comment: was it an infinite sequence of random variables ?@BozoVulicevic

Comment: @Did  why aren't we considering the exact probability . the probability of $X_k>X_1 $ is 0.5 . and the probability of $x_1>X_i$ is 0.5.and i think these two are independent . then the probability of $X_k>X_1>X_i$ is 0.5*0.5 = .25 . why aren't we doing this ?

Comment: @ArnobShamanta Indeed one must be given an infinite sequence of random variables, otherwise the problem makes no sense. // The 0.25 computation is absurd, note that if $X_5$ is the first above $X_1$ one asks that $X_1>X_i$ for every $i$ in $\{2,3,4\}$, not just for one $i$.

Comment: @BozoVulicevic I am a bit at a loss to answer your two last comments. On the one hand the exercise you were given seems to fly high above your head, on the other hand I gave you **two complete solutions**... The best you could do would be to read them slowly and to ponder them, everything one needs is written there. For starters, you might want to note that $L_k$ and $S_k$ are always defined, even when $\nu\ne k$...